# Java drawimage in gameloop

Tags: java, loops, graphics, paint, repaint

I'm trying to learn to program my first game and I would like to understand correctly every step I make. I'll face double buffering and other things later.
I'm just trying to load an image in the game loop.
I have two classes. The first it's just a jframe calling the start method.
I wonder if there is some ugly code, in here (I think so).
So, why are my images not showing up?

```
public class myPanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

//FIELDS
public static int WIDTH = 1024;
public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;
private BufferedImage bg;
private BufferedImage charac;
private boolean running;
private Thread t1;
private int startposX = WIDTH / 2;
private int startposY = HEIGHT / 2;
private int cordX = startposX;
private int cordY = startposY;
int speed = 50;


//METHODS   
public synchronized void start (){
    running = true;
    t1 = new Thread (this);
    t1.start();
}

public synchronized void stop (){
    running  = false;
    try {
        t1.join();
        System.out.println("The game stopped");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
              }
 }

 //INIT
 public myPanel(){

   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
   setFocusable(true);
   requestFocus();
   addKeyListener(this);
 }

 //MAIN RUN METHOD

 public void run(){
           while (running){
           load();
           System.out.println("The game runs");
           repaint();
          }
 }


  //PAINT WITH GRAPHICS METHOD
  public void paint (Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
    g.drawImage(charac, 110, 280, this);

}

//LOAD IMAGES IN MEMORY
public void load (){
            try {
        String path1 = "res/bg.png";
        bg = ImageIO.read(new File (path1));
        String path2 = "res/charac.png";
        charac = ImageIO.read(new File (path2));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Some tips, don't think about threads or multithreading in the beginning, especially if you are new. Also you are consistently reloading your images (every time it is in the loop it loads the images again), you only need to do this once. Also try drawImage(bg,0,0,null). You should also not override paint but paintcomponent, a quick search here will tell you why. Have you added this JPanel to a JFrame and set the JFrame to visible?

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some testing about paint vs paintcomponent and I just saw that the first draws on top of the jpanel background. Anyway, I can't still see anything changing the lines to

```
    public void run(){
    while (running){
    load();
    System.out.println("The game runs");

    }
}



    //PAINT WITH GRAPHICS METHOD

    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(charac, 110, 280, null);
    }
//LOAD IMAGES METHOD AS ABOVE
```

And yes, I've added the panel to the frame, here is the other class

public class Game {

```
public static void main (String [] args){

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setContentPane(new myPanel());
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);

myPanel game = new myPanel();
game.start();

}
```